# Tkinter Canvas move item to top level

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, tkinter-canvas

I have a Tkinter Canvas widget (Python 2.7, not 3), and on this Canvas I have different items. If I create a new item that overlaps an old item, It will be in front. How can I now move the old item in front of the newly created one, or even in front of all other items on the Canvas?

Example code so far:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root,width=200,height=200,bg="white")
canvas.grid()
firstRect = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,10,10,fill="red")
secondRect = canvas.create_rectangle(5,5,15,15,fill="blue")
```

now I want firstRect to be in front of secondRect.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `tag_lower()` and `tag_raise()` methods for the `Canvas` object:

```
canvas.tag_raise(firstRect)
```

Or:

```
canvas.tag_lower(secondRect)
```

Comment: does that raise it by one level or to the front?

Comment: @PeterKramer: To the front I believe. Here's the [link](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.tag_lower-method)

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple items on the canvas and you don't know which one its going to overlap, then do this.

```
# find the objects that overlap with the newly created one
# x1, y1, x2, y2 are the coordinates of the rectangle

overlappers = canvas.find_overlapping(x1, y1, x2, y2)

for object in overlappers:
    canvas.tag_raise(object)
```

Comment: This way you just raise every overlapping item by one level wich will eventually cancel the effect at all. To make it work you will need to put the tag of the object you want to have topmost before 'object', so do this: ```canvas.tag_raise(this_should_be_topmost,object)```.

Comment: An more appropriate approach for that would be ```canvas.tag_raise(this_should_be_topmost,'all')```.